# Raspberry I2C Error: Could not open file `/dev/i2c-1' or

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c, raspberry-pi-zero

I have a problem in getting the I2C working on a Raspberry Zero 2 with Buster (10) 2022-09-22.
The I2C interface is enabled (Preferences > Raspberry Pi Configuration > Interfaces).

If I run the command: i2cdetect -y 1

I get the error: Error: Could not open file `/dev/i2c-1' or...

Any suggestion?

Comment: You might do better asking in [raspberrypi.se].

Comment: Did you try `sudo i2cdetect ...` ?

Comment: Did you try `ls /dev/i2c*` to see if the device special files exist? Did you reboot after `raspi-config` ?